# Cannot declare custom method onto NodeList.prototype of a live NodeList

Tags: javascript

**Can anyone point out why the example only works with static nodeList method "querySelectorAll"?**

I want to create a helper function to aid iterating over child nodes from a live nodeList. However I am getting "myList.on is not a function" if I try using dom querying methods for live NodeLists, i.e. using "getElementsById" & getElementsById.

The only responses I got where cheap shots at collecting points for spotting useless spelling mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NodeList Rocket Science</title>
    <style>
        li {
            list-style: none;
            width: 1em;
            padding: .5em;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 1em;
        }

        li:hover {
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="item">1</li>
        <li class="item">2</li>
        <li class="item">3</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        // Static NodeList - Works, but not method 'getElementsByClassName' or 'getElementById' for live NodeLists!?
        const $items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

        // HTMLCollection of a live NodeList, produces "Uncaught TypeError: $items.on is not a function"
        // const $items = [...document.getElementsByClassName('item')]

        console.log('$items', $items)

        NodeList.prototype.on = function (eventType = '', func = () => {}) {
            this.forEach(
                ($item = undefined) =>
                    $item.addEventListener(eventType, func, false)
            )
        }

        const log = (event = {}, eventTarget = event.target) =>
            console.log(`Clicked node ${ eventTarget.tagName } containing ${ eventTarget.textContent }`)

        $items.on('click', log)
    </script>
```

Comment: `addEvent` !== `AddEvent`

Comment: @DarkCodeWiz JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @DarkCodeWiz - see answer.

Comment: @Utkanos Are you familiar with this error while adding prototypes to NodeList?

Comment: Not specifically, but the case issue was the first problem. Any supplementary issue comes after that.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `AddEvent()`, but calling `addEvent()` - note the difference in case.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues with the code.

```js
NodeList.prototype.AddEvent = function( func ) { 
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i].addEventListener('click', func); //notice this[i] instead of this
  }
}

var myList = document.querySelectorAll('.list'); //notice that element name is not .list so use querySelectorAll
myList.AddEvent(test); //addEvent to AddEvent

function test() 
{
  console.log('Hello')
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  List div
</div>
```

Comment: @gurdvinder372 .querySelectorAll() works but not .getElementsByClassName(...)[0], getElementsByTagName(...)[0] or getElementById(...) - how come this only works on a static node list?